# Why can't I use the HUD with libreoffice in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: libreoffice, 12.10, hud, globalmenu

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 with the latest updates installed, and the global menu works in LibreOffice, even if it is a bit buggy.

However, I can not use the HUD with LibreOffice. No matter what I search for, it only finds the menu entries from the indicators.

I also tried lo-menubar, that I think wasn't as buggy as the standard implementation of the global menu, but it doesn't work with the HUD either.

In every other application, the HUD works fine. Where does this come from?

Comment: Sorry, Ubuntu +1 questions aren't on-topic on the site. We can't support development versions of Ubuntu until it released. See the [faq here](http://askubuntu.com/faq)

Comment: Just for the matter, I can reproduce your bug in 12.10. There are already bug reports filed regarding this. So, you don't have to file another one for this matter.